# Jquery add li elements to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I  have the following html:

```
        <ul id="note-item-lists" class="list-group list-group-sp">
    <li id="1" class="list-group-item">
        <div id="note-4" class="view">
            <button class="destroy close hover-action">×</button>
            <div class="note-name">
                <strong id="new_note_title"> New note </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="2" class="list-group-item">
        <div id="note-4" class="view">
            <button class="destroy close hover-action">×</button>
            <div class="note-name">
                <strong id="new_note_title"> Old note </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Now i wish to store these two `<li>`'s into an array.

For this purpose i have created the following javascript code:

```
    var notes = new Array();

$('.list-group-item').each(function(){
    notes[$(this).id] = $(this);
});
```

However when i debug i get an empty `array` any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you just want: `var $lis = $('.list-group-item')`. That's better than an array for holding DOM elements, it's a jQuery collection. What are you trying to do with those ids? Why are they important for your array?

Comment: @elclanrs The above is an example of a long php generated list :) the real application will have several hundred items where the id matches the id of the database reference

Comment: Why can't you keep your DOM in jQuery collections. When you need to get some elements and retrieve their ids, filter the collection, map the ids, then `.toArray`. Hold onto your jQuery collections as long as you can, that's my advice.

Comment: [jQuery collection](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: @elclanrs Thanks il give it a read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. `id` is a property of a DOM node, not of a jQuery object, so you should use `this.id` instead of `$(this).id`.

```
var notes = [];
$('.list-group-item').each(function() {
    notes[this.id] = $(this);
});
```

Keep in mind that your first `li` element has an `id` of `1`, but Javascript arrays are zero-indexed, so the first element of `notes` (i.e. `notes[0]`) will be `undefined`. I would suggest just pushing them onto the array in the order they appear:

```
var notes = [];
$('.list-group-item').each(function() {
    notes.push($(this));
});
```

Comment: also notes is not an array it should be an object

Comment: @Peter thanks for your help! The id is needed for a later search. however i was thinking javascript doesnt have anything that compares to a hashmap ? does it?

Comment: It does, in Javascript they are called objects. Instead of `var notes = []` you can do `var notes = {}` to use it like a hashmap. (Note that `[]` and `{}` are faster and shorter than `new Array()` and `new Object()`.)

Comment: @ArunPJohny - `notes` can be an array because the ids are numeric. But from the comment after yours it seems the OP does in fact want an object...

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking in chrome console, you should declare it as an object, as you are using it as an object.  Chrome is weird with arrays in the console (well, really they do it right, as in javascript arrays are basically objects, and there aren't associative arrays per se):

```
x = new Array()
//[]
x['a'] = 1
//1
x
//[]
```

But:

```
x = {}
//Object {}
x['a'] = 1
//1
x
//Object {a: 1}
```